# Convolving an image with mean filter infinite times

Tags: induction, convolution, image-processing

I was taught in my image processing class that when a mean filter is applied infinite times on a given image, the intensity of each pixel reaches the same value. I understood this that time entirely on intuition. But looking back, I tried to come up with the formal proof of this result but couldn't make any progress. So is there a way to actually proof this notion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem says that the convolution of a probability distribution with itself $n$ times, as $n\to\infty$, tends to the Normal Distribution with a variance of $n\sigma^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the original distribution.